# django template: Render dictionary within dictionary and elements

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

Using view I have generated following dictionary structure:

```
{'badge-bronze': {'badge_recipients': [<User: aa>, <User: ni>], 'badge': 'badge-bronze', 'page_class': 'meta'}, 'badge-silver': {'badge_recipients': [<User: ni>], 'badge': 'badge-silver', 'page_class': 'meta'}, 'badge-gold': {'badge_recipients': [<User: ni>], 'badge': 'badge-gold', 'page_class': 'meta'}}
```

Here is how I generated the dictionary (only included the part where I construct the dictionary)

```
def contest(request):
    all_badges = badge_data.BADGES.keys()
    data = {}
    for badge in all_badges:
        if badge == 'badge-bronze' or badge == 'badge-silver' or badge == 'badge-gold':
            badge_data_info = get_object_or_404(BadgeData, slug=badge)
            badge_recipients = User.objects.filter(
                                award_user__badge = badge_data_info
                            ).annotate(
                                last_awarded_at = Max('award_user__awarded_at'),
                                award_count = Count('award_user')
                            ).order_by(
                                '-last_awarded_at'
                            )                         
            data[badge] = {
                'badge_recipients' : badge_recipients,
                'badge' : badge_data_info,
                'page_class': 'meta',
            }
    #import pdb
    #pdb.set_trace()      
    return render(request, 'contest.html', {'data':data})
```

In my template I tried to render it as follows:

```
<div id="award-list">
    {% for key,value in data.items %}
        <li>key</li>
        {% for recipient in value.badge_recipients %}
            <div class="user">
                    <span class="thumb">{{ gravatar(recipient, 32) }}</span>
                    <span><a href="{{ recipient.get_absolute_url() }}">{{recipient.username|escape}}</a></span>
                    <span>{{ macros.user_score_and_badge_summary(user) }}</span>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

but i get error saying data is not define and also nothing get render. Based on the answers provided I made the change and now my error is follows: `'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you aren't providing any variable called `data` to the template.

change

```
return render(request, 'contest.html', data)
```

by

```
return render(request, 'contest.html', {'data': data})
```

Comment: I got this error: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: Can you edit your post and show how looks your code now?

Comment: It is possible some of the `badges_recipients` to be `None`?

Comment: no right because I am populating the dictionary if the badge exist... based on the if condition.. but I just updated queestion...

Comment: Obviously you aren't getting in `badge_recipients` what you're expecting. have you debugged the code?

Comment: I am debuging dictionary looks ok i just added the dictionary with two users who obtain badge

Comment: I tried following `    <div id="award-list">
     {% for key,value in data.items %}
      <li>key</li>
     {% endfor %}
    </div>` and this gave me same error 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: I can't see any arror related to your template code. The only suspicious thing is `all_badges = badge_data.BADGES.keys()` but since you have debugged the code and check the dict it's not probable this has to do with the error.  You will not mark this as answered, right? Until we solve the other question?

Answer (score 1):

You should use key 'badge_recipients' in template:

```
<div id="award-list">
    {% for key,value in data.items %}
        <li>key</li>
        {% for recipient in value.badge_recipients %}
            <div class="user">
                    <span class="thumb">{{ gravatar(recipient, 32) }}</span>
                    <span><a href="{{ recipient.get_absolute_url() }}">{{recipient.username|escape}}</a></span>
                    <span>{{ macros.user_score_and_badge_summary(user) }}</span>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div
```

Comment: I tried both the answers it didn't really work. When I tried your answer I get error saying data is undefined.

Comment: You should pass data to template as Miranda wrote, I forgot about it.

Comment: did that actually i edit the question with you guys answers..'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: show how you generate badge_recipients variable in view function

Comment: in that case you should use {% for recipient in value.badge_recipients.all %}

Answer (score 1):

With the help of above answers I managed to figure out the solution for this question:

First fix was:

`return render(request, 'contest.html', data)` to `return render(request, 'contest.html', {'data': data})`

Then when you iterate over dictionary you have to do `dictionary.items()` that was the only thing missing from above answers.

```
<div id="award-list">
    {% for key,value in draw.items() %}
        {% for recipient in value.badge_recipients %}
            <div class="user">
                    <span class="thumb">{{ gravatar(recipient, 32) }}</span>
                    <span><a href="{{ recipient.get_absolute_url() }}">{{recipient.username|escape}}</a></span>
                    <span>{{ macros.user_score_and_badge_summary(user) }}</span>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Wow ... How we missed it?? +1 for the "eagle eye"

Comment: @RaydelMiranda This answer was a collaborative effort so not sure if I should mark this as an answer. I ll just keep it as it. :)